# Pings and replies

Tags: comments, pingbacks

If in a theme for WordPress comments were separated from pings, would it makes sense to keep the option of reply to them in the discussion? (ie visualize the reply link for pings too).

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you could, but it wouldn't make sense to do this. A ping isn't a comment. Nobody wrote on your blog. It's simply notification from a ping-enabled site that shows that site linked to your post. The site that included your link might be a scrapper site, a spammer, or someone who legitimately refers to your post. Either way, they would never see any comments and I don't know what comment anyone could make about a ping.

Comment: what do you mean with technically I could? Pings are treated as comments in WordPress. Thus if I use two wp_list_comments loops to display them separated, the generated markup would be the same except for different classes added to list elements (.pingback, .trackback, .comment) and the lack of gravatar images for pings.

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean by saying that technically you can have replies for pingbacks. It doesn't make logical sense to do so though.

Comment: excuse me but if I don't make a specific callback function to change the markup generated by wp_list_comments(type=pings) then I'll get the reply link! That is why I'm asking if it makes sense to change the original WP markup or if otherwise there's a reason why WP natively leaves the possibility to reply to a ping. I agree with your point, the only thing is that I would like not to make a change that isn't the correct one.

Comment: There is no reason for the reply link to be there. The default WordPress output is there to be managed by the theme. You say your theme separates pingbacks from comments so it should not have included the replies link in its callback. Have a look at how the theme separates comments and pings and adjust this so the replies links are removed from pings. It's a common practise.